# Postgresql - eliminate duplicate entries

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.6

I have following Table:

```
+-----+-----+
| id1 | id2 |
+-----+-----+
| 1   | 2   |
| 1   | 3   |
| 2   | 1   |
| 2   | 3   |
| 5   | 1   |
| 5   | 2   |
+-----+-----+
```

I don't want to get duplicated entries like

```
1 | 2
2 | 1
```

At long last I need following:

```
+-----+-----+
| id1 | id2 |
+-----+-----+
| 1   | 2   |
| 1   | 3   |
| 2   | 3   |
| 5   | 1   |
| 5   | 2   |
+-----+-----+
```

What is the best solution to doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by my self. I think, my question was poorly worded.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN u.id1 > u.id2 THEN u.id2
        ELSE u.id1
    END as id1,
    CASE WHEN u.id1 < u.id2 THEN u.id2
        ELSE u.id1
    END as id2
FROM table u
```

I sorted the smaller values to the left.
**DISTINCT** eliminate the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE (id1, id2) IN 
(SELECT t1.id1, t1.id2 FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.id1 = t2.id2 AND t1.id2 = t2.id1);
```

EDIT:

Oh, I thought you wanted to remove them both.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE (id1, id2) NOT IN(
SELECT least(id1, id2), greatest(id1, id2)
FROM table);
```

Or

```
SELECT DISTINCT least(id1, id2), greatest(id1, id2)
FROM table
```

Comment: This will delete **both** the twins.

Comment: Thanks  for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

If you can have at most two entries per pair, then:

```
select id1, id2
from t
where id1 < id2
union all
select id1, id2
from t
where id2 > id1 and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id1 = t.id2 and t2.id2 = t.id1);
```

If you just wanted unique pairs, I would use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select least(id1, id2), greatest(id1, id2)
from t
group by least(id1, id2), greatest(id1, id2);
```

EDIT:

You can also do this using window functions or `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (least(id1, id2), greatest(id1, id2)) t.*
from t
order by least(id1, id2), greatest(id1, id2);
```

Comment: the first solution is I was looking for. But you need the table "t" two times. In my case, "t" is a subquery, so it will take more time then my solution. but thank you anyway. :)